# Qt Issue with displaying PDF files

Tags: c++, qt

My program scans the directory for MetaPost files and detects the modified ones. Then it uses a python script to produce PDF files from the modified files. After the PDF files are produced, the program updates and displays a user selected active PDF file. I use poppler library to load a PDF file into QImage. And then I use QGraphicsView to view the image.

So basically it works like this: I modify a MetaPost file with some text editor and my program should display the modified image.

The problem: I save the changes, but my program won't display the new PDF file. I have to save the file again and only then the new PDF file gets displayed. I am sure, that the script creates the PDF files correctly.

Do you know what could the problem be?

Comment: Random idea: If you have to save the file again, it sounds to me as if you don't have access permission before you do so. Are you sure the script correctly closes the newly created pdf so that you don't try to access an open file?

Comment: The script ganerates the pdf files using 'pdflatex'. So I think that this is not the problem.